# TPM error while installing ubuntu 14.04 | hardware HP mini 400 g3 PC

Tags: tpm

[image]

error occur while installing ubuntu 14.04.
also disabled TPM setting in BIOS but same error

Comment: Looks like users have experienced this issue before on numerous different machines, and have found a work around. Link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305719/a-tpm-error-7-occurred-attempting-to-read-a-pcr-value-in-centos